# Not able to run unit test in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio

I am not able to run unit test on Visual Studio 2013. Initially when the unit test was created, it was able to run and debug. But after some time, I am not able run unit test from Visual Studio.

[image]

[image: Run and debug button disabled]

**The Run and Debug items are disabled.**

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2013 are you running?

Comment: Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Comment: Can you click that runbutton showing above the unittests, and then run all?

Comment: I have updated my question. The Run and Debug Test menu items are disabled. Initially they are ok.

Comment: Have you tried reïnstalling Visual Studio?

Comment: That is one of the option. I have just install VS update but it does not help. I will try reinstall VS.

Comment: Is this is the case for *all* solutions? Like if you create a new, empty solution and a new unit test, can you run them?

Comment: I have found a solution to this problem. I remove the Unit Test project. Then I added it back. I realize I am able to run my Unit Test again.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this problem. I removed the Unit Test project. Then I added it back. I realize I am able to run my Unit Test again.